# Accidentally messed up /etc/passwd

Tags: ubuntu, passwd

I accidentally modified the default shell program /bin/bash for my user in /etc/passwd. I didn't set a root password in my ubuntu server installation.

Now I can't even login. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot up into a live disk, mount the partition and fix /etc/passwd :)

Answer (score 4):

Or .. start your box in `single user mode` and modify your `passwd` file - [ubuntu single user mode link.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)